# Render PDF Page to Bitmap using Pdfium

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, pdfium

I'm trying to convert a PDF page to a .NET `Bitmap` using [Pdfium](http://pdfium.googlesource.com). I want to use it directly in the WPF so WinForm methods is not intended. I already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411460/bitmap-graphics-vs-winform-control-graphics) question (based on my initial understanding) as I was trying to do that using `FPDF_RenderPage`. From what I learnt till now from [SDK](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitPDF_SDK20_Guide.pdf) and the sole .NET port of it ([PdfViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer)) there are two ways to render to a bitmap.

I want to know if I'm doing the steps correctly in first method specifically the memory device context and what is needed to correctly bring the native bitmap to .NET in second method.

1. Using `FPDF_RenderPage` by feeding a memory device context

   ```
   var hMemDC = NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
   IntPtr hDC = NativeMethods.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

   // Create a bitmap for output 
   var hBitmap = NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);

   // Select the bitmap into the memory DC 
   hBitmap = NativeMethods.SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

   IntPtr brush = NativeMethods.CreateSolidBrush((int)ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.White));
   NativeMethods.FillRgn(hMemDC, NativeMethods.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, width, height), brush);

   // _file is an instance of PdfFile from PdfViewer port
   // Now render the page onto the memory DC, which in turn changes the bitmap                 
   bool success = _file.RenderPDFPageToDC(
                page,
                hMemDC,
                (int)dpiX, (int)dpiY,
                bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height,
                true /* fitToBounds */,
                true /* stretchToBounds */,
                true /* keepAspectRatio */,
                true /* centerInBounds */,
                true /* autoRotate */,
                forPrinting
           );

   hBitmap = NativeMethods.SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

   Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
   ```
2. Using [`FPDF_RenderPageBitmap`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/DLL311/group___f_p_d_f_v_i_e_w.html#ga78e560fce2c6efa038afd4ab64526baa)

   ```
   IntPtr bitmapHandle = NativeMethods.FPDFBitmap_Create(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, 0);    

   // _file is an instance of PdfFile from PdfViewer port
   bool success = _file.RenderPDFPageToBitmap(
      page,
      bitmapHandle,
      (int)dpiX, (int)dpiY,
      bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height,
      true /* fitToBounds */,
      true /* stretchToBounds */,
      true /* keepAspectRatio */,
      true /* centerInBounds */,
      true /* autoRotate */,
      forPrinting
   );                

   if (!success)
     throw new Win32Exception();
   else
   {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[bounds.Width * bounds.Height * 4];
       Marshal.Copy(bitmapHandle, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       bitmap = Convert_BGRA_TO_ARGB(bytes, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
   }
   ```

// Convert BGRA to ARGB

```
    public Bitmap Convert_BGRA_TO_ARGB(byte[] DATA, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap Bm = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        int index;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // BGRA TO ARGB
                index = 4 * (x + (y * width));
                Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                     DATA[index + 3],
                    DATA[index + 2],
                    DATA[index + 1],
                    DATA[index + 0]);
                Bm.SetPixel(x, y, c);
            }
        }
        return Bm;
    }
```

Render:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you aren't accounting for the stride for each row (think DWORD alignment). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049838/correct-stride-formula-for-bitmap) formula should help.